# Deleting records with Basic Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm looking at implementing `Model.sync.deleteRecord()` for use with Ember-Data Basic Adaptor.

According to the docs, adapter must call `didDeleteRecord()` once record has been successfully deleted from the server.

However, I can't find good example on how to actually call `didDeleteRecord()`. After looking at the source, the best I come up with this:

```
    deleteRecord: function(record, process) {
        my_api.remove(record.get('id')).then(function() {
            var r = process(record);
            r.store.adapter.didDeleteRecord(r.store, r.type, r.record);
        });
    }
```

Is there any better, less uglier ways to call `didDeleteRecord()`?

Comment: The basic adapter is gone since few months